# Oscilloscope 'ground' displaying at +2.4VDC

Tags: ground, oscilloscope

When ground-coupled, trace is a dead flat zero volts on the display.  At 5V per division,  DC or AC-coupled, with ground lead clipped to any point on circuit ground, the minimum voltage displayed is +2.4V even when probing the same trace as the ground lead is clipped to.

At smaller values of V/div the voltage of 'ground' is still above zero volts but less so, to a degree which appears to correspond with the resolution.

This happens regardless of probe used. The circuit is powered from a bench power supply, +12VDC, the PSU and oscilloscope are both referenced to the same earth ground.

I'm sure I'm making some dumb error, thoughts?

Comment: Are the power supply chassis ground and "-" output isolated?

Comment: Continuity check with DMM gives a solid beep when probes put across chassis and '-' terminals, ditto the PSU's plug's ground pin and '-' terminals (does that answer your question? ).

Comment: @SimonOwen - Hi, Can you edit the question please & add (a) scope trace images in the "ground-coupled" and "measuring 0V seems to show +2.4V" states; (b) photos of the scope & PSU front panels, so that we know what you are looking at; (c) some background / context e.g. has this always happened with this scope & PSU config?  If not, what has changed since the (supposedly ground-referenced) PSU output last showed 0V on the scope? (d) try a different PSU or, if not available, just a 9V battery, and prove that the scope + probe combination can show 0V when probe & probe gnd are on the battery -ve.

Comment: `DMM gives a solid beep` ... why would you not measure the resistance?

Comment: analogue or digital oscilloscope?

Comment: I did measure the resistance, and found about 10R between the '-' terminal which I was using and the chassis/plug ground pin. The other '-' terminals measure a fraction of 1 Ohm. Embarrassing admission: the PSU is one I assembled from parts from a photocopier; clearly my first project wasn't quite as successful as I'd thought! Thank you, issue solved.